# How to install a Parallels Windows VM using an answers.xml file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, parallels

Is it possible to install Windows on a Parallels (10) Virtual machine while using my own answers.xml file for unattended installation?

Following the Microsoft documentation, in order to use the file I should have the Windows installer on one plugged in drive (usually a DVD) and the answers file on another one.

However I am not able to plug an external USB drive into the virtual machine while it is being booted for the first time.

Comment: Can you not use a .ISO instead?  Even Virtual PC had that feature.

Comment: I am using an ISO for the installer image. However I need to insert an _additional_ media containing my answers.xml file.

Comment: the answers.xml file should be contained with the the same .ISO image.

Comment: I see, so far I had strictly no luck creating an image or any sort of bootable media that would work in Parallels. I'll post another question for that.